# clearing stack of activities with just one press

Tags: android, service, android-activity, stack, task

I have a launching `Activity` A1 which has a start button which starts a `Service` S1:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG1, "Starting Update Service");
                startService(serviceIntentS1);
            }
        });
```

S1 depending on some condition starts `Activity` A2:

```
if (giveninteger>=2)
       {   
           Intent intentA2= new Intent(this, A2.class);
           // following line to avoid exception
           intentA2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //to avoid exception
           startActivity(intentA2);  

         }
```

A2 subscribes to S1 and from A2 user can see periodically updated data by the aid of S1. A2 has following code to stop S1 service:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG2, "Killing Update Service");
            stopService(serviceIntentS1);

              } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.i(TAG3, "Service was not running " + e.toString());
        }
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }
```

My problem is that, if the update runs 10 times from A2, user has to press back button 10 times to exit `Activity` A2. That is instances of A2 are accumulated in `Activity` stack. I tried all flags during launch of A2 from S1, but without success. I want to exit the `Activity` A2 with just one back press, no matter how many times the update runs.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "update"? Are you using BroadcastReceiver in A2 for catching Intents from S1 or what?

Comment: yes i am using BroadcastReceiver in A2 and getting a webservice

Comment: So how did you got those multiple A2 instances in the activity stack? Which component starts all of it? If the S1 Service then why it startActivity() each time instead of sendBroadcast()? If any of the others, then which?

Comment: thanks praetorian for your comments. The app has a complex work flow and i needed to start the activities from service instead of using sendBroadcast(). please see my comments below.i solved the problem finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a SingleInstance of A2 so that irrespective of the number times A2 is launched only one instance remains and you need to press back button only once.
Define this attribute in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity android:launchMode"singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep...the problem is, if i use this, activity A2's data is not updated from service S1.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks Rajdeep for directing me to the manifest file. I had to do the following settings for activity A2 in manifest file: android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"  
 android:noHistory="true"