# Android reuse activity from activity stack and clear it

Tags: android, android-activity

I have application with main activity and some more.
On each other activity there is the logo of the application.
When user presses the logo button, I want to get back to the main activity.

I do not want to create new intent, since activity aready on the activity stack.

How can I get it - use the one on the stack?
How can I clear the whole activity stack, so back button will actually exit from the application instead of getting back to the previous activity?

Yoav

Comment: You need to try and understand `Activity LifeCycle` from Android Documentation and look at the `finish()` function.

Answer (score 4):

> I do not want to create new intent, since activity aready on the activity stack.

If you start an activity (via intents or any other way) which was already started and is on the stack , then Android just takes that same instance of the activity and places it on top of the stack. A new instance is not created. Ofcourse this happens if you did not manually kill the activity (by calling `finish()` in it).

> How can I clear the whole activity stack, so back button will actually exit from the application instead of getting back to the previous activity?

Its not recommended to override the back button to quit the application in every activity(Unless your app has strong reasons to do so). generally the app should let the user go back to the previous activity when he presses the back button (which is what a user might be expecting).
If you still would like to quit with the back button then you can override the back button function and launch the intent that leads to the home screen:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a somewhat similar problem. The following link might be helpful for you:

[clearing stack of activities with just one press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277533/clearing-stack-of-activities-with-just-one-press)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.
Don't call finish() on Home/Main activity. 
For Ex: Say you have 4 activities.. If your requirement is like this .. Act1-->Act2-->Act3-->Act4-->Act1 . So, don't call finish() on Act1. But call finish() on Act2, Act3 while you are going to other activity. So when you click on logo in Act4, just call finish(). So, automatically you will come back to Act1 which is your Main activity. 
If you have logo in Act2, Act3 also then call finish() on click of logo to go back to Main. But remember to call finish() on Act2 while you are going from Act2 to Act3